# Set font size using a variable in gnuplot

Tags: variables, gnuplot, font-size

How can I set a font size using a variable in gnuplot 4.6.
I am trying to do something like:

```
  fontSize = 20;
  set xlabel "Time" font ", fontSize"
```

Comment: Provide the traceback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simply using concatenation operator `.` of text and integers:

```
set xlabel "Time" font ", ".fontSize
```